# PHP Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$following

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've tried everything on how to echo out `following` but it keeps giving me an error or it returns blank. such as `echo $s->following` gives error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$following`. I want the first following in the object array only to output. Code Object below:

```
object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["relationship"]=> object(stdClass)#12 (2) { ["source"]=> object(stdClass)#13 (16) { ["id"]=> int(49216720948621475) ["id_str"]=> string(18) "56435616498624156" ["screen_name"]=> string(15) "lmfao" ["following"]=> bool(true) ["followed_by"]=> bool(false) ["live_following"]=> bool(false) ["following_received"]=> NULL ["following_requested"]=> NULL ["notifications_enabled"]=> NULL ["can_dm"]=> bool(false) ["blocking"]=> NULL ["blocked_by"]=> NULL ["muting"]=> NULL ["want_retweets"]=> NULL ["all_replies"]=> NULL ["marked_spam"]=> NULL } ["target"]=> object(stdClass)#14 (7) { ["id"]=> int(53486451354989563589) ["id_str"]=> string(18) "6873168431643435468" ["screen_name"]=> string(10) "sunshine" ["following"]=> bool(false) ["followed_by"]=> bool(true) ["following_received"]=> NULL ["following_requested"]=> NULL } } }
```

Comment: I think because "following" is inside "source" and "source" is inside "relationship". So you may try this to see if it works : 
`$s->relationship->source->following`

Comment: @Long King I think that worked. It outputs a 1. I'm guessing if it outputs a 1 that makes it TRUE correct? Because when it outputs FALSE the output is blank.

Comment: ya, 1 is true, 0 is false

Comment: if you don't mind i will put my comment as answer ?

Comment: But it doesn't show a 0, it's just blank does it matter if it doesn't show a 0?

Comment: you can just check like this `if($s->relationship->source->following) { // do something }` So it only matter if it true.

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted and give its a thumbs up please :)

Comment: It looks like your answer is solved. If you don't mind, would you please put that as an answer to your question rather than including it in the question itself? That makes it easier for the future people who are more likely to skim the question and just skip by to the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because "following" is inside "source" and "source" is inside "relationship". So you may try this to see if it works : `$s->relationship->source->following`